# Weird results when extracting residuals from egarch model from rugarch package

Tags: r

When I tried to extract residuals from an EGARCH model using rugarch package. the results appear weird. It shows the date starting from 1970 while my data is from 2012. Then I tried with the data that include dates, the results appear exactly the same. My data is daily log returns of a share and is stored in CVS file.

Much appreciate if anyone can tell me where the issue is!

I tried with the data that excludes the date column and include the date column but the results are the same and show incorrect date in the first column. It also shows something like time in the second column (which ...nonsense!!).

```
PreGFC=read.csv("PreGFCdata.csv")
pregfc=PreGFC[,-1] #exclude date column 
pregfc=na.omit(pregfc)
testing.egarch<-ugarchfit(ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "eGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)),distribution.model="sged"), data=pregfc$RAU) 
residuals(testing.egarch, standardize=TRUE)
```

```
                     [,1]
1970-01-02 08:00:00  3.038888e-01
1970-01-03 08:00:00 -4.669357e-01
1970-01-04 08:00:00  2.436350e-01
1970-01-05 08:00:00  1.701233e+00
...
1972-05-20 08:00:00 -1.004648e+00
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason for this is because unix time starts in 1970. You're going to need to parse the data column using as.Date() or the various options within the lubridate package. If you provide a reproducible example, I will be able to show you how that would look more precise to your data, but essentially the column should be passed through lubridate::date() after import.

Comment: thank you so much for answering my question. Sorry I am newbie, so if I know how to provide a reproducible I will do it straight away, but I am not sure how to do it. I have my data on the csv file from 2012 to 2018 so I have like 870 rows. Should I make it into a sample list like 10 data and attach the file here if that help? The data I used is the daily stock price that i downloaded from Bloomberg, then I converted them into first difference log. Then I use the data in the code by the using the function read.csv.

Comment: This is the data that I used 

<Date RAU
10/05/2002 0.002030907
13/05/2002 -0.001887811
14/05/2002 0.00170784
15/05/2002 0.009450522
16/05/2002 0.003174615
17/05/2002 0.004256911
21/05/2002 -0.001823192
22/05/2002 0.004071876
23/05/2002 -0.002404349>

Comment: Sorry I was trying to put into the code..
This is the data that I used 
```
Date RAU
10/05/2002 0.002030907
13/05/2002 -0.001887811
14/05/2002 0.00170784
15/05/2002 0.009450522
16/05/2002 0.003174615
17/05/2002 0.004256911
21/05/2002 -0.001823192
22/05/2002 0.004071876
23/05/2002 -0.002404349
```